# Vertically aligning my div within the body

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a CSS way to vertically align my div within the body element?

The thing is my div will have a different height each time, so its not constant.

These are the things I've tried but they dont work:

```
body { vertical-align: middle; }

#mainContent { 
   vertical-align: middle;
}

// Also this
body { margin-top: 20%; margin-bottom: 20%; }
```

Comment: There are many links online about this; it's a tricky thing to do unless you know the height of the div. http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: vertical-align works only for table-cell elements..

Comment: Would it just be easier with javascript? I am better a javascript than css.

Comment: If you want to use javascript, you can just get the div size after the page is loaded and position it with javascript.

Comment: Check these examples (although they're divs within divs): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328314/center-block-vertically-and-horizontally-with-dynamic-width-and-height and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967217/vertical-align-middle-doesnt-work

Comment: Is there anything else you need to complete this question?

Comment: i got it done purecss and without table-layout

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Honestly, my opinion is often that if you're doing vertical alignment you should still be using a table. I know it's often frowned upon, but it is still the simplest and cleanest way to vertically center something.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Your DIV here.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td {vertical-align: middle;}
```

Comment: you are doin’ it wrong. Using tables for markup slow down your sites rendering

Comment: @VladimirStarkov that seems to be common conception, but is it really true? I really wonder. Because guys answering my question said it doesn't really matter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111348/is-there-any-research-data-that-shows-div-with-css-is-faster-than-table

Comment: @deathlock I will duplicate here: ‘both pages[table-way and table-free] loads simultaneously. But table free markup will be rendering part by part, and table-way page will be rendered only by successfull assignment all the elements with it's css rules'

Comment: I typically try to use tools for the purpose they have been created for when one exists. I try to avoid misusing tools that weren't designed to solve my problem when others exist that don't violate their purpose as much.

Comment: I guess this is from person to person, but if I need a hammer and my boss is giving me a screwdriver telling me it is all I need and that I have to learn to use it correctly, I'd take that f***ing piece of rock instead and just get the job done.

Answer (score 17):

### I did it without table: ([demo on dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/2872671))

The main trick in this demo is that in the normal flow of elements going from top to bottom, so the `margin-top: auto` is set to zero. However, for an absolutely positioned element acts the same distribution of free space, and similarly can be centered vertically at the specified `top` and `bottom` (does not work in IE7).

This trick will work with any sizes of `div`.

#### HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

#### CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: @deathlock I have already noted about browser support in my answer.

Comment: you're wonderful! I always think margin auto only works horizontally and now you've show me the whole new world of margin auto :)

Comment: @LawrenceMok it's the clone answer. Checkout original http://stackoverflow.com/a/13356401/1057730

Answer (score 9):

A common problem indeed. I have seen many people offering straight css solutions for this but they all require knowing the height of the element needing to be centered, so no help there.

I usually do it this way using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    site.resize();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        site.resize();
    });
});

var site = {
    resize: function(){
        var new_margin = Math.ceil(($(window).height() - $('#mainContent').height()) / 2);
        $('#mainContent').css('margin-top', new_margin + 'px');
    }
};
```

Comment: I know it's not CSS only but this is a great solution. Particularly if you're using Bootstrap or another framework that already depends on jquery.

Answer (score 6):

Surprisingly (or not), the `vertical-align` tool actually works best for this job. **Best of all, no Javascript is required.**

In the following example, I am positioning the `outer` class in the middle of the body, and the `inner` class in the middle of the `outer` class.

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/tLkSV/513/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <span></span><div class="outer">
        <span></span><div class="inner">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }
#container {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%; }
span { 
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
.inner {
    background: red;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;    
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
```

Vertical align works by aligning the centers of elements that are next to each other. Applying vertical-align to a single element does absolutely nothing. If you add a second element that has no width but is the height of the container, your single element will move to vertically center with this no-width element, thus vertically centering it. The only requirements are that you set both elements to inline (or inline-block), and set their vertical-align attribute to `vertical-align: middle`.

*Note: You may notice in my code below that my `<span>` tag and `<div>` tag are touching. Because they are both inline elements, a space will actually add a space between the no-width element and your div, so be sure to leave it out.*

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using tables, and without adding extra elements:

```
<ul>
    <li>One short item</li>
    <li>Any real long text...</li>
    <li>Another short item</li>
</ul>
```

And then the CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: table-row;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jmgonet/g8dbT/)

It would work with any other kind of hierarchy, including div, p, etc.