# How to centralize div crossbrowser

Tags: html, css

I would like to know a way in CSS to center a div in a  without being dependent set margin-top and down, control the height with magic numbers.

The forms that have learned all these disadvantages, some better and worse, but all are dependent on something, and would like a permanent solution to any browser (at least IE8+).

I want centralize horizontally and vertically a div element without magical numbers. Where the height of the div to grow dynamically and automatically be calculated and centralized.

To clarify, is an example of what I DO NOT want. For use widht and height defined leaves no flexibility, and have to be manipulating the height added to each item using js.

http://jsfiddle.net/QsWfg/

```
<div id="container"></div>

#container { position: absolute; width: 380px; height: 360px; left: 50%; top:50%;      padding: 30px; margin-left: -220px; margin-top: -210px; background: #000; }
```

Comment: Centralize horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Your question is not healthy, unless it is packed with code.  This is entirely opinion based.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do? You want to magically center a div horizontally and vertically, but not hardcode any values? You have said that the example is what you *DO NOT WANT* but haven't really clarified what it is that you do want.

Comment: See the post now please.

Comment: Look this fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/yUwyZ/ If I add the code of answer, don't work. Look please.

Comment: [Center block vertically and horizontally with dynamic width and height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328314/center-block-vertically-and-horizontally-with-dynamic-width-and-height)

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

Codepen example: http://cdpn.io/BuDLo

**HTML**

```
<div class='modal-overlay'>
  <div class='modal-box'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal-overlay {
  background: black;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-box {
  background: white;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: No man, exists magic number in your code. The widht and height is defined. I need a generic solution.

Comment: What are these *magic numbers* and where can I find them? The width and height are only defined to give an example. Otherwise the box wouldn't appear at all.