# Place circle in center of div

Tags: html, css

I have the below code where I've created three circles to show the steps of my form. I'm trying to center the circle inside it's enclosing div. I've tried to place them in center using margin for circle-text class `margin: 0 auto;` But circle doesn't come to the center of div.

```css
.circle-text {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  /*change this and the width
for the size of your initial circle*/
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*make it pretty*/
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font: 18px "josefin sans", arial;
  /*change this
for font-size and font-family*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
    <div class="circle-text">
      Step 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
    <div class="circle-text">
      Step 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
    <div class="circle-text">
      Step 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I place circles in the middle of their enclosing div's ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to centralize div crossbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318685/how-to-centralize-div-crossbrowser)

Comment: @AngelHotxxx Not so... This is totally a problem with the implementation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `table-cell` cannot be centred using `margin: auto` as it works only for `<div>` with known widths. I have added `line-height` matching the height.

```css
.circle-text {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  /*change this and the width
for the size of your initial circle*/
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*make it pretty*/
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font: 18px "josefin sans", arial;
  /*change this
for font-size and font-family*/
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
    <div class="circle-text">
      Step 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
    <div class="circle-text">
      Step 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
    <div class="circle-text">
      Step 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]